# Redirect with React Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I am returning a custom redirect URL for OAuth using a Nodejs back end. I am trying to get React to redirect the user to this URL however it's adding localhost to the front of it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import axios from "axios";

class Test extends Component {

async componentDidMount() {
const profileData = await axios.get("/connect");
this.props.history.push(profileData.data);
}

render() {
return <div />;
}
}

export default withRouter(Test);
```

So let's say the profileData.data returned string is http://www.google.com, the webpage gets redirected to http://localhost:3000/http://www.google.com.

Is there a way of redirecting with React to make it redirect to a specific URL rather than it trying to redirect to a sub page?

Comment: The react router will only be able to help you if you're staying on your own site. How about just a `window.location.href = profileData.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put a set the location href inside your componentDidMount function. I would write it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get("/connect")
    .then((response) => {
      window.location.href = response.data
    })
}
```